# Constructing a list of function applications

Tags: scala, haskell

I have a Haskell function which I would like to translate into Scala. The Haskell function is:

```
valid3 :: (Bool -> Bool -> Bool -> Bool) -> Bool
valid bf = and [bf p q r | p <- [True, False], 
                           q <- [True, False],
                           r <- [True, False]]
```

'valid3' is a higher-order function in that it takes a function as an argument. The function which it takes as an argument accepts three boolean variables and returns a boolean value. Finally `valid3` returns a boolean value itself.

I tried to translate this into Scala but am getting stuck on how to do the conjunction in the `yield` part. This is what I have so far (this does not compile as is):

```
def valid3 (bf : (Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) => Boolean) : Boolean = {
  for (i <- List(true, false); 
       j <- List(true,false); 
       k <- List(true,false)) yield bf(i,j,k)
}
```

I am not sure if I am approaching this correctly in Scala. Any tips on how to do this in idiomatic Scala would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `for` comprehension returns a list so you can use `forall` for `and`:

```
def valid3 (bf : (Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) => Boolean) : Boolean = {
  val results = for (i <- List(true, false); 
       j <- List(true,false); 
       k <- List(true,false)) yield bf(i,j,k)
  results.forall(identity)
}
```

If you don't want the intermediate variable you can use:

```
def valid3 (bf : (Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) => Boolean) : Boolean = {
  (for (i <- List(true, false); 
        j <- List(true,false); 
        k <- List(true,false)) yield bf(i,j,k))
  .forall(identity)
}
```

`forall` takes a predicate and returns `true` if the predicate is true for every element in the list. The corresponding function in Haskell is `all` which has type `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`. If you want to return true if the predicate is true for any list element you can use `exists` e.g.

```
results.exists(identity)
```

This corresponds to the Haskell function `any`. As far as I know there are no directly corresponding functions for `and` and `or` in Scala which operate on lists of `Boolean` but you could easily define them:

```
def or(s: GenTraversableOnce[Boolean]) = s.exists(identity)
def and(s: GenTraversableOnce[Boolean]) = s.forall(identity)
```

Comment: Great. I was getting stuck because I was trying to find a way to do it without storing the results in a variable like the Haskell implementation.

Comment: @I.K. - You can call remove the temporary variable if you want by changing it to `(for .. yield bf(i, j, k)).foreach(identity)`

Comment: i just tried that but i'm getting syntax errors. could you post this alternative solution as I have probably not got the syntax down correctly.

Comment: how does the `forall` replace the `and`? what if I decided to replace the `and` with `or`, will this still work?

Comment: alternately you could use the comprehension to do the and for you: `{ val tf = List(true,false); for (i <- tf; j <- tf; k <- tf; !bf(i,j,k)) yield () }.isEmpty`

Comment: @I.K. - I'm not sure what you mean - the `bf` argument in the Scala version is effectively the same as the `bf` argument in the `Haskell` version so you can pass whatever boolean function you want to evaluate e.g. `valid3((a, b, c) => a && b || c))`. Do you also want to be able to provide the list predicate function as an argument which is currently hard-coded to be `and/forall`?

Comment: Yes it's the list predicate function which I wanted to generalise. However, I had a re-think and it's not needed; forall and exists are sufficient. Thanks.

Comment: My opinion is that trying to stack everything in one line should be avoided.  Defining intermediate variables with good names really help for readability.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution which is quite different from what you originally wrote, but I think it is clearer.  Also it can be generalized for more than three arguments.  I'm using bit manipulations to generate all the combinations of booleans.

```
  def findAllBooleanCombos(nArgs: Int): Seq[Seq[Boolean]] = {
    def convertByteToBooleans(byte: Int, nArgs: Int): Seq[Boolean] =
      Range(0, nArgs).map(bitIndex => ((byte >> bitIndex) & 1) == 1)

    Range(0, 1 << nArgs).map(byte => convertByteToBooleans(byte, nArgs))
  }

  val nArgs = 3
  val isAlwaysTrue = findAllBooleanCombos(nArgs).forall(bools => 
                                               f(bools(0), bools(1), bools(2)))
```

An alternative solution which does not use bit manipulation tricks and which is more general (more Stream-ish):

```
  def combinations[A](stream: Stream[A], n: Int): Stream[List[A]] = n match {
    case n if (n <= 0) => throw new IllegalArgumentException()
    case 1 => stream.map(List(_))
    case n =>
      val streamNMinus1: Stream[List[A]] = combinations(stream, n - 1)
      stream.flatMap(a => streamNMinus1.map(listNMinus1 => a :: listNMinus1))
  }
  combinations(Stream(true, false), 3)
```

**EDIT**:  I recently encountered the Scala has a built-in function `combinations`, which is defined on many types (`List` for example).  However, it does not really work here since the number of elements in the combinations have to be smaller or equal to the number of elements in the collection.

Comment: If anyone has any idea on how to pass the three boolean arguments to `f` directly, I would be interested.  `f(bools:_*)` does not work here, but I'm looking for a similar idea.